# Difference between two quantifier placements for a single statement

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Considering a predicate Q(y,x) stating that `x is greater than y`, what is the difference between.

$\forall x \exists y$   $Q(y, x)$

and

$\exists y \forall x$   $Q(y, x)$

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you meant that second statement to be $\exists y \forall x$   $Q(y, x)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited it

Comment: OK, then see my Answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement says that for every number there is a greater number (true: for any $x$, you can always pick $x + 1$ as a greater number)

The second statement says that there is a number greater than all numbers, which is clearly false! (in fact, 'all numbers' would include itself, so besides $y$ being greater than all *other* number (which is already false, since there is no greatest number), $y$ would also have to be greater than itself!)

Comment: Thanks. I have another questions related to this problem.
Considering the parse tree for $\exists y \forall x$   $Q(y, x)$
Is y bound or free? Because the first quantifier that we found when going upwards from y is $\forall x$  so I wonder if y is still bounded.

Comment: @PierreP. The $y$ would indeed not be bounded at the point of $\forall x \: Q(y,x)$, but when you go up from there and get to $\exists y \forall x \: Q(y,x)$, then the $y$ is bounded. So, in the whole statement $\exists y \forall x \: Q(y,x)$, both variables are bound.

Comment: Thanks! It's crystal clear for me know!

Comment: @PierreP. Great! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

> $$\forall x \exists y ~Q(y,x)$$

For every $x$, there's a $y$ such that $Q(x,y)$. but it could be a different $y$ for every $x$.

> $$\exists y \forall x ~Q(y,x)$$

For every $x$, there's a $y$ such that $Q(x,y)$. but it is the same $y$ for every $x$.